# Purposefully make instance attached to ELB as unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

Is there any way to make an instance attached to an ELB unhealthy purposefully using boto ?

I tried few methods and non of them working so far.

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There is no AWS API call that can change the health status of an instance. (Auto Scaling has this capability, but not Load Balancing).

You could use the [`deregister_instances()`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/elb.html#boto.ec2.elb.ELBConnection.deregister_instances) API call, which would effectively achieve the same result.

The [Register or Deregister EC2 Instances for Your Classic Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-deregister-register-instances.html) documentation says:

> Deregistering an EC2 instance removes it from your load balancer. The load balancer **stops routing requests** to an instance as soon as it is deregistered. If demand decreases, or you need to service your instances, you can deregister instances from the load balancer. An instance that is deregistered remains running, but **no longer receives traffic** from the load balancer, and you can register it with the load balancer again when you are ready.
>
> When you deregister an instance, Elastic Load Balancing **waits** until in-flight requests have completed if **connection draining** is enabled.

Comment: Just had one more doubt.
Suppose there are 10 instances are registered in ELB.
If i remove an instance from an ELB, what will happen ?
I mean, what will happen to requests actively served by that instance.

Comment: Updated answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, We can do that in the below scenario.
Let's assume that you have loadblancer(myloadbalancer), an instance attached with it and PingPath configuration as such below.

```
Ping Protocol: HTTP
Ping Port: 80
Ping Path: /
```

Just add boto3 code to edit the health check configuration as below and you can see the magic(Instance OutOfService).

```
client.configure_health_check(
LoadBalancerName='myloadbalancer',
HealthCheck={
    'Target': 'HTTP:80/hjkx',
    'Interval': 30,
    'Timeout': 5,
    'UnhealthyThreshold': 5,
    'HealthyThreshold': 3
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Two other options:
1. Temporarily disable the web server / process that's responding to the health check. In our case, we were running Java webapps with and nginx proxy in front of it. Shutting down the nginx proxy made the health check fail while the Java app would still be running.
2. Temporarily firewall the port that the ELB uses to perform the health check on. You could do this via a call to the AWS api.